# A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script invokes by https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js invoked by document.w

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, document.write

I have a lot of warnings in my Chrome console about a cross-site script being invoked by a document.write.
I'd like to get rid of this message but it is invoking by a js script downloaded via the google tag manager (https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js).
What can I do?

The warming message is:
A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.

Henk Jelt